# Scanf function with strings

Tags: c++, scanf

I need to read input from user. The input value may be string type or `int` type. 
If the value is `int` then the program insert the value into my object.
Else if the value is string then it should check the value of that string, if it's "end" then the program ends.

```
Halda h; //my object
string t;
int tint;
bool end=false;

while(end!=true)
{
    if(scanf("%d",&tint)==1)
    {
        h.insert(tint);
    }
    else if(scanf("%s",t)==1)
    {
      if(t=="end")
          end=true;
      else if(t=="next")
          if(h.empty()==false) 
              printf("%d\n",h.pop());
          else 
              printf("-1\n");
    }
}
```

The problem is that scanning string doesn't seem to work properly.
I've tried to change it to: `if(cin>>t)` and it worked well.
I need to get it work with `scanf`.

Comment: is this C or C++? If C, what's string?

Comment: It's c++ (<string> is included)

Comment: The question is rather: why did you tag this C if it's C++?

Comment: `scanf("%s"...);` expects the argument to be a `char` buffer. Whereas `string` is a class.

Comment: 1. Why do you *need* to get it to work with scanf? 2. scanf %s is unsafe and should never be used (buffer overflow). 3. scanf should not be used for user input (it's not line based and error recovery is hard/impossible). 4. Using flag variables for flow control is mildly obfuscatory. Why not just `break` if that's what you mean?

Comment: I use scanf because someone has told me that it's faster for big inputs.

Comment: 1. That's not necessarily true (did you benchmark it?). 2. You don't have big inputs. 3. You don't know how to use scanf, so it won't help you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specifier `%s` in the `scanf()` format expects a `char*`, not a `std::string`.

From C11 Standard (C++ Standard refers to it about the C standard library):

> Except in the case of a % specifier, the input item (or, in the case of a %n directive, the
>    count of input characters) is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier. If
>     the input item is not a matching sequence, the execution of the directive fails: this
>    condition is a matching failure. Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>    the **format** argument that has not already received a conversion result. **If this object
>   does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
>   in the object, the behavior is undefined**.

Anyway, here there's is no real reason to prefer the C way, use C++ facilities. And when you use the C library, use safe functions that only reads characters up to a given limit (just like [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), or `scanf` with a width specifier), otherwise you could have overflow, that leads again to undefined behavior, and some errors if you're luck.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really bad way to check for end-of-input. Either use an integer or use a string.

If you choose string, make provisions to **convert** from `string` to `int`.

My logic would be to first check if it can be converted to integer. if it can be, then continue with the logic. If it can't be(such as if it's a `float` or `double` or some other `string`) then ignore and move on. If it can be, then insert it into `Halda`'s object.

Sidenote: Do not use `scanf()` and `printf()` when you're working with C++.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `string` refers to `std::sring` this program doesn't have defined behavior. You can't really use `std::string` with `sscanf()` You could set up a buffer inside the `std::string` and read into that but the string wouldn't change its size. You are probably better off using streams with `std::string` (well, in my opinion you are always better off using streams).